# Firebase database url change

Tags: angular, firebase, youtube, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am using Firebase in my app. However, when I input my data in the Firebase admin console on the web, it changes the URL.

The iframe HTML:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" [src]="getSantizeUrl(feature.video)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Example of my Firebase:

```
{title:"title", video:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/rtoxRg-kbt0"}
```

Once I click ENTER in the Firebase Admin console on the web, it then changes to this (**NOTE**: As you can see the `embed/` changed to `watch?v=` of the URL):

```
{title:"title", video:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuc4dp0qHSc"}
```

This causes my application to show this error:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuc4dp0qHSc' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`
```

Is there a way to stop Firebase changing the URL? Or is there an alternative for me to display videos on my app without getting that error?

Many thanks.

Comment: This needs a [mcve] that shows how you are inputting the data, etc.

Comment: I don't think this is Firebase's fault. That error is a block from youtube. You can only watch youtube videos from a youtube embeded window

Comment: @cartant, I simply just add the youtube url into the firebase database, but after I click ENTER the url changes from `embed/` to `watch?=v`.

Comment: @Joakim, yes that is the problem, I use the `embed/` but it changes in firebase to `watch?v=`

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. Are you saying you are entering it through the Firebase admin console on the web? Or via code in your app?

Comment: Sorry, Firebase admin console on the web. Also, it seems to work now, but it shows this error every 30 secs. `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id. Redirect from 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id' to 'data:text;charset=utf-8,' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.youtube.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it worked fine the next day. Also, the error i got `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id. Redirect from 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id' to 'data:text;charset=utf-8,' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.youtube.com' is therefore not allowed access` was to do with adblocker.